# Onclick event for "li" in a for loop when using createElement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an event listener (onclick) onto every `li` element that gets created in a specific for loop - using JavaScript.

First I tried using `tempLi.onclick` (see code below for context), but it wouldn't run the function. After that I searched for the issue here on Stackoverflow, and I read that this method I'm using below should work - but it doesn't (not in my case at least).

```
if (users.length !== 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        let tempLi = d.createElement('li');
        tempLi.className = 'btn btn-primary knappur'
        tempLi.innerHTML = users[i];
        getId('usersUl').appendChild(tempLi);
        (function(value) {
            tempLi.addEventListener("click", function() {
                alert(value);
            }, false);
        })(users[i]);
        getId('usersUl').innerHTML += '<br>';
    }
}
```

The code is in a function called `loginPrepare`:

```
let loginPrepare = () => { ... }
```

How can I execute code when I click on the generated `li` (`tempLi`)?

**EDIT: The code that I'd like to run when clicked on the "li" is `login(users[i])`**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Indeed, that should successfully alert the user object when clicked. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Side note: No need for the `if` at the beginning of that, all it does is make the code slightly more complicated. It doesn't gain you anything.

Comment: I'm afraid the edit really doesn't help us. You'd just use `login(value)` where currently you have `alert(value)` and, again, it would work. To usefully answer the question, we need to see that MCVE.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem with the original approach is because you're editing innerHTML inside the loop. You're blowing away all of your previous handlers each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the event handler on your ul and rely on event bubbling instead of attaching an event handler to each. It would look something like this.

```
document.getElementById('usersUl')
  .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.hasClass('knappur') {
      // Do your work
    }
  });
```

Comment: Not a bad suggestion, but not an answer to why the OP's code isn't working. Since the OP's code should work, we don't know this code will; first we have to know why the OP's isn't working.

Comment: `e.currentTarget` will be the `ul`, not the `li`, so it won't have the class (unless it happens to, but...). You'd need `e.target` for that, and if you used `e.target`, you'd be assuming the `li` will never have subordinate elements (you'd need the relatively-new `closest` or a loop to avoid that assumption).

Comment: Yup, you're right. Should've been e.target. I was going with the case here of no children, but yes, otherwise you would need to walk the dom.

Comment: Also, "do your work" is **very** vague, as it's unclear how the user would identify the correct user in the event handler.

Comment: The question was also very vague about what they're doing in the handler...

Comment: A good suggestion indeed, but I forgot to write that the code that will be executed is users[i] (unique for each 'li')

Comment: Doesn't look at all vague to me -- they want to use `value`, and they know that `value` will be what `users[i]` was in the loop, because they're correctly capturing it.

Comment: If you store a data-user-id or data-idx attribute on the li you could use that to reference into your users array.

Comment: See my edited question.  When clicked, "login(users[i])" should be executed

Comment: When I implemented your answer (removed the .hasClass part), it worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: document.getElementById('usersUl')
  .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   login(e.target.innerHTML)
  });

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a function inside a loop, referencing the ever-changing index `i`, which, when the loop is done might be a completely different value than what you think it is.

Also, I think this way you are attaching the event-listener before the `tempLi` has had time to be properly integrated into the dom.

Third: you don't need to create a new event-listener for each list item. One is enough.//

Try this instead:

```
if (users.length !== 0) {
    const list = getId('usersUl')
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        let tempLi = d.createElement('li');
        tempLi.className = 'btn btn-primary knappur';
        tempLi.innerHTML = users[i];
        tempLi.setAttribute('data-user', users[i])
        list.appendChild(tempLi);
        //list.innerHTML += '<br>';  don't do this btw, <br />s aren't valid children of lists!
    }
    list.addEventListener("click", event => {
       const user = event.target.getAttribute('data-user');
       alert(user);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve event binding to HTML in very simple way using JQuery like below:

```
  $("#usersUl").on('click',function(e){
    //what we do
    });
```